# How to load a PUMA robot in the existing environment in OpenRAVE 0.9

Tags: robotic-arm, motion-planning

I have a PR2 robot in an environment, which can be seen on the GUI of OpenRAVE.

Now, how can I load a [PUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_Universal_Machine_for_Assembly) robot arm in the same environment?

Comment: Not sure how much of a help this is, but... there is a [PUMA arm](http://openrave.org/docs/0.8.0/ikfast/unimation-pumaarm/#robot-unimation-pumaarm) listed in the [OpenRAVE robots database](http://openrave.org/docs/0.8.0/ikfast/robots/)... although it only has a 50% success rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple robots and environments can be loaded.  Simply load them and position the robots.  Here is a Python example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from openravepy import *

env = Environment()
env.SetViewer('qtcoin')

env.Load("pr2-beta-sim.robot.xml")
env.Load("puma.robot.xml")

pr2 = env.GetRobot('pr2')
puma = env.GetRobot('PumaGripper')

puma.SetTransform([1,0,0,0,0,1,0])
```

Run this with something like: `ipython -i my2robots.py`

For an example in C++, see [this example](http://openrave.org/docs/latest_stable/coreapihtml/orloadviewer_8cpp-example.html).